# How to merge three columns without repeating same values

Tags: r, merge, multiple-columns

I have three columns:

```
A     B     C
2018  NA    NA
2018  NA    NA
2018  NA    NA
NA    2019  NA
2018  2018  NA
NA    2017  2017
```

I want to create a new column `year`, where it will be like this: year = 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2017.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your data instead of screenshots. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored in an object called `df`:

```
df$year <- rowMeans(df[,c("A", "B", "C")], na.rm = TRUE)
```

The code works if your columns are of type numeric.

An alternative is from the tidyverse with `coalesce`, which gives you the first non-missing element in each row:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(year = coalesce(A, B, C))
```